# Show inequality (probably using the induction)

Tags: analysis, inequality, induction

I'm having a problem with this inequality.

Show that for every integer k $\ge 2$ and n:

$\frac{n^{k+1}}{k+1} \ge 1^k + 2^k +...+(n-1)^k $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a consequence of *Bernoulli's inequality*:

> For all $n\in\mathbf N$, if $h>-1$, then $\enspace(1+h)^n\ge 1+nh$.

Indeed, suppose, by the inductive hypothesis, $\;\dfrac{n^{k+1}}{k+1} \ge 1^k + 2^k +...+(n-1)^k\;$ for some $n\ge 0$. We deduce that
$$\frac{n^{k+1}}{k+1}+n^k \ge 1^k + 2^k +...+(n-1)^k+n^k,$$
so to prove the inductive step, it will be enough to prove that
\begin{align}
\frac{(n+1)^{k+1}}{k+1}\ge\frac{n^{k+1}}{k+1}+n^k&\iff(n+1)^{k+1}\ge n^{k+1}+(k+1)n^k \\%
&\iff \biggl(1+\frac1{n}\biggr)^{k+1}\ge1+(k+1)\frac 1n,
\end{align}
which is exactly *Bernoulli's inequality*.

Comment: Thank you ! I should definitely pay more attention to previous theorems.

Answer (score 1):

A different approach: Notice

$$ \frac{n^{k+1}}{k+1}= \int\limits_0^n x^k dx \geq \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac{n}{n} \left( i \frac{n}{n} \right)^k = 1^k + 2^k + ... + (n-1)^k $$

Comment: I like this answer alot, unfortunately we haven't covered derivatives yet, not to mention integrals :)